# Interraction of C-function on unrelated numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I encountered some really weird behaviour in one of my code. It look like this :

```
count=0
while True:
    print "loop number : ", count
    print "minx : ", minx # [[118.]]
    image=camera.read_frame() # C function, grab a frame and return a Ndarray with the image, does NOT interact with minx.
    print "type of minx : ", type(minx) # numpy.ndarray
    print "inside value of minx : ", minx[0][0] # 118.
    print "minx : ", minx # freeze execution on the n-th time, computer dependant.
    count+=1
    #do other stuff
```

So I have this loop : I grab a frame, do some spot detection on it, and store the coordinate of the spot in a variable minx.
Everything works fine, but on the n-th loop (1870 on my computer, but it depend on the computer), the call to the C-function that grabs the image doesn't work and the array returned is corrupted.
This is an issue I'm working on, but what I want to know is :

- How can this have an effect on the `minx` variable ?
- How is it possible that minx exists, that I can retrieve its type and inside value, but not the whole array?

To clarify, I can read this on the console :

> loop number : 0
>
> minx : [[118.]]
>
> type of minx : numpy.ndarray
>
> inside value of minx : 118.
>
> minx : [[118.]]

... # 1869 Loops

> loop number : 1869
>
> minx : [[163.]]
>
> type of minx : numpy.ndarray
>
> inside value of minx : 163.
>
> Freeze here

I don't have any Error/Exceptions, it just freeze. I don't have any memory leak either. I know this is caused by the C-function, because I went back to an old version of it and it works.

What I can't figure out is how the C-function can have an effect on the minx variable when they are completely unrelated? And how come I can access the inside value of minx but not the whole array?

Comment: Does your C function or other APIs called in that function happen to use libc memory functions (`malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, `free`)? Because that would interfere with Python for sure.

Comment: Yes, I strongly suspect this is the issue here with the C-function. But shouldn't it work on separate memory space than the Python? And how can it induce this behaviour for minx ?

Comment: It should work on separate space, except when a Python object is involved. Since I don't know your C function, I just wanted to mention this as a possibility. See also https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html